# How do I fix hard disk "Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed"

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, filesystem, apfs

How can I resolve the `Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed` error I'm getting when trying to verify my hard drive?

So far these are the steps I've taken:

In Terminal I ran:

```
diskutil list
```

I identified the disk:

```
    /dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +524.9 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            103.7 GB   disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 21.0 MB    disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                519.0 MB   disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM  

                2.1 GB     disk3s4
```

I tried to run a verification as follows:

```
diskutil verifyVolume disk3s1
```

This resulted in the following output/errors:

```
    Verifying file system
    Volume is already unmounted
    Performing fsck_apfs -n -x /dev/rdisk3s1
    error: failed to read container superblock
    File system check exit code is 8
    Restoring the original state found as unmounted
    Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
    Underlying error: 8: Exec format error
```

I'm worried if I use the following command I will delete the existing data while repair ing the disk?

```
diskutil repairDisk disk3s1
```

The disk is encrypted and requires a password, and the disk does not appear in Disk Utility in macOS.

**How can I proceed to resolve this?**

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to clarify the exact version of macOS you have installed and the model of Mac you're using?

Comment: I test the hard disk on MacBook Air for debug (11 inches, mid 2012). Version high Sierra 
SSD that does not work has installed High Sierra in another Mac book pro.

Comment: `error: failed to read container superblock` suggests that the first block (4096 bytes) of the APFS container `disk2s2` have become corrupted. You can use my [`apfs-inspect`](https://github.com/jivanpal/apfs-tools) tool to try and get a better idea of what's wrong with the partition.